# Why are these Date objects different?

Tags: javascript, date

I am wondering why those two Date objects have different output in console. In my opinion it should be the same but I can be wrong :)

```js
var twoLinesSetup = new Date();
twoLinesSetup.setHours(0, 0, 0);
var inlineSetup = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0)

console.log('twoLinesSetup', twoLinesSetup);
console.log('inlineSetup', inlineSetup);
```

And the console

> twoLinesSetup: Mon May 08 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200
>
> inlineSetup :1494194400521

Why is it so?

Comment: Because `setHours()` does return milliseconds as a number, not the `Date` instance?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`twoLinesSetup` contains the return value from instantiating the `Date` constructor, which returns a new `Date` instance object.

`inlineSetup` contains the return value from the `setHours` method, which returns [the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours)

Answer (score 2):

inlineSetup stores the return value of setHours. It is "[A Number, representing the number of milliseconds](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sethours.asp) between the date object and midnight January 1 1970"

twoLinesSetup is an actual object, which you do manipulate. The console output - the "toString" method if you want it like that, is the formatted string representation you see.

In theory you should see the same number by doing [twoLinesSetup.getTime()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the return value of the `setHours()` call to `inlineSetup`. This is not the `Date` object but a number representing the milliseconds of the date.